# Special characters in alias

Tags: bash, alias

Is it possible to have special characters in alias?

A very dumb example, just to make the point:

```
ls | xargs cat | grep "this"
alias ->='xargs cat | grep '
ls | -> "this"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins), an alias must be a ["name"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html#Definitions):

> alias [-p] [name[=value] …]
>
> ... If arguments are supplied, an alias is defined for each name whose value is given.

and:

> name
>
> A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an identifier.